# Obfuscate in-line Tailwind CSS classNames in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have a NextJS 13 application using Tailwind CSS. I have code like the following

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center mt-16 mx-auto">
          ....
</div>
```

When I use developer tools, my entire application skeleton is exposed, making it easy for anyone to download the HTML and duplicate it.

How can I obfuscate my classNames so that they are hashed? I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

All of the existing solutions cover cases where the CSS is defined on another file and imported into the Components for use.

Comment: Why are you worried about this? Anything sent to the client is visible and, while obfuscation is possible, it's a lot of effort for little return

Comment: No, I didn't. It's a comment, not an answer. Even if op obfuscates the class names the accompanying css would still be accessible. Why so hostile @osman